# Why does Kafka change store name

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a problem with my application.

Code:

```
KTable<Long, byte[]> table = stream.groupByKey().aggregate(() -> null , (key, oldVal, newVal) -> {
        return newVal;
    }, Materialized.<Long,byte[],KeyValueStore<Long,byte[]>>as("networkStore").with(longSerde, byteSerde));
```

here I set the Store Name to be `networkStore`, but when I list Kafka topics, the store's name is `network-service-KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000001-changelog`

What I want is: -the store's name to be `networkStore`, so that I can read from it later.

When I Try to read from the store now, it gives me the following exception:

> org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.InvalidStateStoreException: The state store, networkStore, may have migrated to another instance.
>       at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.QueryableStoreProvider.getStore(QueryableStoreProvider.java:60)
>       at org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams.store(KafkaStreams.java:1039)
>       at com.maxflow.networksservice.utils.NetworksServiceUtils.updateGraphForCompany(NetworksServiceUtils.java:41)
>       at com.maxflow.networksservice.consumer.NodesConsumer.run(NodesConsumer.java:99)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: It should use the "networkstore" as store name. Did you try to reset the application ID and check ?

Comment: how to reset the application id ?

Comment: Either try to reset the application ID using https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Kafka+Streams+Application+Reset+Tool  or re-run with new application ID to check if your store name is used.

Comment: It is not working, I tried changing the application ID and it still uses the `network-service-KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000001-changelog` name
I'm on windows and I don't have `bin/kafka-streams-application-reset.sh` or the `.bat` equivalent

Comment: If I use the .reduce() method, the store is called `network-service-KSTREAM-REDUCE-STATE-STORE-0000000001-changelog`. I'm using Kafka 2.0.1

Comment: Calling `Materialized.<Long,byte[],KeyValueStore<Long,byte[]>>as("networkStore").with(longSerde, byteSerde)` seems to be wrong because both methods are `static` and thus calling `with` does create a new object and is no applied to the object creates via `as` -- you should rather call `Materialized.<Long,byte[],KeyValueStore<Long,byte[]>>as("networkStore").withKeySerde(longSerde).withValueSerde(byteSerde)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use following:

```
KTable<Long, byte[]> table = stream.groupByKey().aggregate(() -> null , (key, oldVal, newVal) -> {
        return newVal;
    }, Materialized.with(longSerde, byteSerde).as("networkStore"));
```

`Materialized.as().with()` is overwriting the custom name with internal name. Hence you 
should call `.as()` method after `.with()`.  You can read more details here.

https://kafka.apache.org/20/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/Materialized.html#with-org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serde-org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serde-

Another option is using `.withKeySerde()` and `.withValueSerde()` method with custom Store name as given below.

```
Materialized.<Long,byte[],KeyValueStore<Long,byte[]>>as("networkStore").withKeySerde(longSerde).withValueSerde(byteSerde)
```

Comment: I don't thinks this will work as expected. Calling `Materialized.<Long,byte[],KeyValueStore<Long,byte[]>>with(longSerde, byteSerde).as("networkStore")` seems to be wrong because both methods are `static` and thus calling `as` does create a new object and is no applied to the object creates via `with` -- you should rather call `Materialized.<Long,byte[],KeyValueStore<Long,byte[]>>as("networkStore").withKeySerde(longSerde).withValueSerde(byteSerde)`

Comment: @MilanPanic : please check the suggestion from Matthias also.

Comment: @NishuTayal Maybe update your answer? Not sure if everybody read the comments :)